# How to make class visible just inside the lib?

Tags: android

Let's say there is a lib that has such structure

```
main->java->MyInterface.java
main->java->foo->FirstClass.java (implement MyInterface.java)
main->java->boo->SecondClass.java (implement MyInterface.java)
```

Problem is there, when I build and then implement this lib in separated project I can without any problem call `MyInterface` class from project, but I don't want that user even know that I have such class in my lib.

P.S. Interface `MyInterface.class` I took just for an example actually it could be any other bunch of classes that lib is using, but I don't want that user know about them. I give to user `API` that user can use and I don't wan't to show him all my classes...

How to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Prevent them from using it because it might be wrong?  Don't publicize that as part of the API.  You can make it a private class, but that's trivially worked around if someone really wants to. Its not possible to stop them from doing stupid things.   Don't let them know it exists at all?  Not possible, anyone who runs your code under a debugger will be able to see the concrete implementation of the interface.  And that's necessary, I've needed to step into libraries to find and fix bugs in their implementation, or discover assumptions they made but didn't document.

Comment: @GabeSechan ok, no problem user can debug it and so on, but I don't want that he has access to these classes from out project. These classes only for internal usage...